# Storing array of words from string in a list of full names in R

Tags: r, substring

I have a list of `120777` records which contains names of people. I want to store an array of name parts for each record in the dataset. I tried this in R.

```
my_list$name_parts<- strsplit(my_list$name, " ")
```

I get a `my_list$name_parts` as a list of `120777` items. When I try querying the number of words in each name using `length(my_list$name_parts)`, I get `120777` for all.

Comment: `my_list$name_parts` is a `list` and the length of a list is the number of elements it contains. You want the length of each element and you can obtain it through `sapply(my_list$name_parts,length)`

Comment: An other option is using the plyr library and run llply(my_list$name_parts,length). Or ldply() if you want the output to be in a dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use this simple example:

```
my_list <- list()
my_list$name <- c("toto t. tutu", "foo bar")
```

To get the number of words, you can do that:

```
lapply(strsplit(my_list$name," "), length)
```

which gives in the simple example above:

```
[[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]]
[1] 2
```

To avoid getting a list, you can even do:

```
unlist(lapply(strsplit(my_list$name," "), length))
[1] 3 2
```

Comment: Shouldn't the "a" be "my_list$name" ?

Comment: This solution works!
But also please tell me -- if I were to store arrays of word_parts (not the length of the array) in as a variable in my dataset my_list, how would I do that?

Comment: What wuld be word_parts?

Comment: The array (achieved on strsplit) whose length we just computed for  each name.

For eg. If name in first record of list is "John Cambell", word_parts would be ["John", "Cambell"]

Comment: If you want to store a list of arrays: `my_list$word_parts <- lapply(strsplit(my_list$name," "), length)`. If you want to store the array all words from all names: `my_list$word_parts <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(my_list$name," "), length))`

Comment: Isn't this going to give me the length of the word parts? I want the absolute name parts (like first name, middle name, ... last name) in an array for each name string

Comment: Your last method returns lengths of each arrays formed from the names. I want each record to contain the array of word parts.
strsplit(my_list$name, " ")[[9998]] gives me array formed the 9998th name. Similarly, I want the arrays formed every row and store it in a variable. 
Can that be done without a for loop?

Comment: I suggest you to ask another question on the site. It will be easier and clearer :)

Comment: I got the answer. I am sorry for getting confused about this. strsplit(my_list$name," ") would give me character arrays for every record. Thanks for the help